Connecting to mariaDB in Github action
I know there are multiple related questions but I can't get this to work.
I'm working on a Github action to test my Django app using MariaDB and Selenium before deploying. I have simplified it to just running the tests for now.
I have reviewed my secrets and know they are correct.
I have tried running services on both localhost and in a container, but neither can seem to resolve the database address.
I have tried it like this:
name: Deploy

on:
  push:

jobs:
  django-tests:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    services:
      db:
        env:
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD }}
          MYSQL_DATABASE: ${{ secrets.MYSQL_DATABASE }}
          MYSQL_USER: ${{ secrets.MYSQL_USER }}
          MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.MYSQL_PASSWORD }}
        image: mariadb:11.5
        options: >
          --health-cmd="healthcheck.sh --connect --innodb_initialized"
        ports:
          - 3306:3306
      selenium:
        image: selenium/standalone-chrome
        ports:
          - 4444:4444

    steps:
    - name: Check out code
      uses: actions/checkout@v3

    - name: Debug Hostname Resolution
      run: |
        ping -c 4 localhost:3306 || echo "Failed to resolve 'db'"

    - name: Set up Python
      uses: actions/setup-python@v4
      with:
        python-version: 3.12

    - name: Install dependencies
      run: |
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip
        pip install -r requirements.txt

    - name: Run Django Selenium Tests
      env:
        SECRET_KEY: ${{ secrets.DJANGO_SECRET }}
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD }}
        MYSQL_DATABASE: ${{ secrets.MYSQL_DATABASE }}
        MYSQL_USER: ${{ secrets.MYSQL_USER }}
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.MYSQL_PASSWORD }}
        DATABASE_URL: mysql://${{ secrets.MYSQL_USER }}:${{ secrets.MYSQL_PASSWORD }}@localhost:3306/${{ secrets.MYSQL_DATABASE }}
        DISPLAY: ":99.0"
      run: |
        python manage.py migrate
        python manage.py test

and also running in a python container without exposing ports and connecting to "db" directly (the services name).
Any help would be appreciated!
EDIT: After the suggestions I have tried this:
name: Deploy

on:
  push:

jobs:
  django-tests:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    services:
      db:
        env:
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD }}
          MYSQL_DATABASE: ${{ secrets.MYSQL_DATABASE }}
          MYSQL_USER: ${{ secrets.MYSQL_USER }}
          MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.MYSQL_PASSWORD }}
        image: mariadb:11.5
        options: >
          --health-cmd="healthcheck.sh --connect --innodb_initialized"
        ports:
          - 3306:3306
      selenium:
        image: selenium/standalone-chrome
        ports:
          - 4444:4444

    steps:
    - name: Check out code
      uses: actions/checkout@v3

    - name: Set up Python
      uses: actions/setup-python@v4
      with:
        python-version: 3.12

    - name: Install dependencies
      run: |
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip
        pip install -r requirements.txt

    - name: Run Django Selenium Tests
      env:
        SECRET_KEY: ${{ secrets.DJANGO_SECRET }}
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD }}
        MYSQL_DATABASE: ${{ secrets.MYSQL_DATABASE }}
        MYSQL_USER: ${{ secrets.MYSQL_USER }}
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.MYSQL_PASSWORD }}
        DATABASE_URL: mysql://${{ secrets.MYSQL_USER }}:${{ secrets.MYSQL_PASSWORD }}@db:3306/${{ secrets.MYSQL_DATABASE }}
        DISPLAY: ":99.0"
      run: |
        python manage.py migrate
        python manage.py test

Which ended up with this error:
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5655800Z Traceback (most recent call last):
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5665064Z   File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.12.7/x64/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 279, in ensure_connection
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5666352Z     self.connect()
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5669423Z   File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.12.7/x64/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5671011Z     return func(*args, **kwargs)
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5672289Z            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5674308Z   File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.12.7/x64/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 256, in connect
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5676195Z     self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5677594Z                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5679067Z   File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.12.7/x64/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5680472Z     return func(*args, **kwargs)
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5753937Z            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5755453Z   File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.12.7/x64/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 256, in get_new_connection
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5756735Z     connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5757406Z                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5758128Z   File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.12.7/x64/lib/python3.12/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 121, in Connect
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5758780Z     return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5759232Z            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5759909Z   File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.12.7/x64/lib/python3.12/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 195, in __init__
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5760514Z     super().__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5761349Z MySQLdb.OperationalError: (2005, "Unknown MySQL server host 'db' (-3)")
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5761701Z 
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5761956Z The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5762251Z 
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5762502Z Traceback (most recent call last):
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5763054Z   File "/home/runner/work/fiubecas/fiubecas/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5763520Z     main()
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5764052Z   File "/home/runner/work/fiubecas/fiubecas/manage.py", line 18, in main
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5764667Z     execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5765558Z   File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.12.7/x64/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 442, in execute_from_command_line
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5766425Z     utility.execute()
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5767391Z   File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.12.7/x64/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 436, in execute
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5768250Z     self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5769058Z   File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.12.7/x64/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 413, in run_from_argv
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5769778Z     self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5770531Z   File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.12.7/x64/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 459, in execute
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5771184Z     output = self.handle(*args, **options)
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5771542Z              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5772533Z   File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.12.7/x64/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 107, in wrapper
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5773212Z     res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5773629Z           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5774340Z   File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.12.7/x64/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 101, in handle
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5775018Z     self.check(databases=[database])
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5775753Z   File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.12.7/x64/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 486, in check
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5776400Z     all_issues = checks.run_checks(
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5776790Z                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5777461Z   File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.12.7/x64/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 88, in run_checks
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5778181Z     new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5778686Z                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5779427Z   File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.12.7/x64/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/core/checks/model_checks.py", line 36, in check_all_models
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5780494Z     errors.extend(model.check(**kwargs))
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5780977Z                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5781644Z   File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.12.7/x64/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 1690, in check
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5782338Z     *cls._check_fields(**kwargs),
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5782688Z      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5783348Z   File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.12.7/x64/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 1825, in _check_fields
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5784077Z     errors.extend(field.check(**kwargs))
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5784435Z                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5785083Z   File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.12.7/x64/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 2788, in check
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5785827Z     *super().check(**kwargs),
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5786191Z      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5786883Z   File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.12.7/x64/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 2066, in check
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5787557Z     *super().check(**kwargs),
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5787869Z      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5788576Z   File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.12.7/x64/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 274, in check
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5789302Z     *self._check_backend_specific_checks(**kwargs),
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5789762Z      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5790558Z   File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.12.7/x64/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 486, in _check_backend_specific_checks
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5791395Z     errors.extend(connections[alias].validation.check_field(self, **kwargs))
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5792093Z                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5792859Z   File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.12.7/x64/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/validation.py", line 25, in check_field
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5793557Z     field_type = field.db_type(self.connection)
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5794063Z                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5794746Z   File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.12.7/x64/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 874, in db_type
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5795556Z     column_type = connection.data_types[self.get_internal_type()]
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5796000Z                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5796656Z   File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.12.7/x64/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 47, in __get__
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5797574Z     res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5797992Z                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5798692Z   File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.12.7/x64/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 141, in data_types
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5800145Z     if self.features.has_native_uuid_field:
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5800778Z        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5802311Z   File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.12.7/x64/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 47, in __get__
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5803493Z     res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5804194Z                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5805551Z   File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.12.7/x64/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/features.py", line 331, in has_native_uuid_field
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5806879Z     is_mariadb = self.connection.mysql_is_mariadb
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5807711Z                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5808903Z   File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.12.7/x64/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 47, in __get__
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5810167Z     res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5810879Z                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5812235Z   File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.12.7/x64/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 444, in mysql_is_mariadb
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5813538Z     return "mariadb" in self.mysql_server_info.lower()
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5814344Z                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5815659Z   File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.12.7/x64/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 47, in __get__
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5816884Z     res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5817577Z                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5818969Z   File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.12.7/x64/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 430, in mysql_server_info
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5820229Z     return self.mysql_server_data["version"]
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5820999Z            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5822117Z   File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.12.7/x64/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 47, in __get__
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5823409Z     res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5824142Z                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5825455Z   File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.12.7/x64/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 404, in mysql_server_data
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5826338Z     with self.temporary_connection() as cursor:
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5826736Z          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5827430Z   File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.12.7/x64/lib/python3.12/contextlib.py", line 137, in __enter__
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5901008Z     return next(self.gen)
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5901589Z            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5928046Z   File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.12.7/x64/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 695, in temporary_connection
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5929266Z     with self.cursor() as cursor:
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5929742Z          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5930902Z   File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.12.7/x64/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5931855Z     return func(*args, **kwargs)
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5932395Z            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5933429Z   File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.12.7/x64/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 320, in cursor
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5934699Z     return self._cursor()
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5935284Z            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5936267Z   File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.12.7/x64/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 296, in _cursor
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5937302Z     self.ensure_connection()
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5938358Z   File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.12.7/x64/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5939381Z     return func(*args, **kwargs)
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5939981Z            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5941033Z   File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.12.7/x64/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 278, in ensure_connection
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5942119Z     with self.wrap_database_errors:
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5942725Z          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5943674Z   File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.12.7/x64/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 91, in __exit__
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5944842Z     raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5947129Z   File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.12.7/x64/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 279, in ensure_connection
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5948233Z     self.connect()
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5949212Z   File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.12.7/x64/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5950167Z     return func(*args, **kwargs)
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5950648Z            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5951843Z   File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.12.7/x64/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 256, in connect
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5952939Z     self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5953633Z                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5954633Z   File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.12.7/x64/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5955570Z     return func(*args, **kwargs)
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5956182Z            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5957253Z   File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.12.7/x64/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 256, in get_new_connection
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5959297Z     connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5959995Z                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5961338Z   File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.12.7/x64/lib/python3.12/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 121, in Connect
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5962570Z     return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5963175Z            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5964279Z   File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.12.7/x64/lib/python3.12/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 195, in __init__
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5965577Z     super().__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
2024-11-27T09:41:03.5966372Z django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2005, "Unknown MySQL server host 'db' (-3)")


It would be db as the hostname. You can't ping a port like that, try to omit. and db as hostname in DATABASE_URL.

Can you show the logs of which step failed to resolve and the messages associated with it?

Hi @danblack, yes, sorry, my bad. I have edit the question. I'm focusing on the line:
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2005, "Unknown MySQL server host 'db' (-3)")
But you may see something else I'm missing.

You could be right about localhost being right. It would be db if it was in another container. It might be the case that ubuntu:latest already has MariaDB or MySQL running on the host. When the container comes up it will be conflicting on 3306. port: 3307:3306 and then use localhost:3307 in the DATABASE_URL. If that doesn't work, try using 127.0.0.1:3307 because there depending on implementation localhost can map to a socket, which is inaccessible inside the container.

Also mariadb:11.5 received it last update and these are going to move pretty as the release model given one stable version before moving to the next (unless a LTS). If you want to keep track with a GA stable version mariadb:latest.  If you care able long term support versions mariadb:lts maps to last LTS release.
